# Run at same time signed and unsigned release

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an build.gradle file with next code:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('./src/main/filename')
        storePassword 'pass'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'keypass'
    }

    release_unsigned {

    }

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    release_unsigned
    {
       minifyEnabled true
       proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
}
```

So... for getting 2 files, one signed and one unsigned (I need this because of resons) I run it twise:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

then

```
gradlew assembleRelease_unsigned
```

How can I create those 2 files only with one command, one run for both?

Comment: Assuming that you want to build all types, `gradlew assemble` should do the trick. If you want to build more than one type but not all, then I don't know.

Comment: Have you found any solution?